# What is this strange syntax inside `find -exec`?

Tags: bash, find, exec

Recently I've came across a strange bash script, which is used to call a custom bash function from inside `find -exec`. I've developed following simple script to demonstrate the functionality I need to get explained.

In the following example, function `foo` will be called for each `find` result.

```
foo()                                                                                                                                                 
{
    echo "$@"
}
export -f foo

find . -exec bash -c 'foo "$@"' bash {} \;
```

Can someone explain how the part after `-exec` is interpreted?

---

**UPDATE:**

To further simplify this, after exporting `foo` as above, following gets executed for each `find` result (assume there is a file named `my_file`).

```
bash -c 'foo "$#"' bash my_file
```

And this produces the output `myfile`. I don't understand how this works. What does the second `bash` does there? Any detailed explanation is appreciated.

(Please note that this question is not about `find` command. Also please ignore the functionality of function `foo`, I just wanted to export some function)

Comment: `bash -c 'echo $0'`  will output 'bash'.  Similarly  `bash -c 'echo $0' bash` will also output 'bash'.
The reason it’s done, is if you wanted to pass other parameters in, then they will be $1, $2, $3  `bash -c 'echo asdf' bash abc def ghi` and $0 will remain as 'bash'.  You can put anything there, it's just a parameter to your command string(the thing in single quotes after bash -c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand you need to know 4 things:

1. The `find` action `-exec` allows you to apply a command on the found files and directories.
2. The `-c` `bash` option is documented as follows:

   ```
   BASH(1)
   ...
   OPTIONS
   ...
          -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from
                    the first non-option  argument  command_string.
                    If  there are arguments after the command_string, they
                    are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

   ...

   If bash is started with the -c option, then $0 is set to the first
   argument after the string to be executed, if one is present.
   Otherwise, it is set to the filename used to invoke bash, as given
   by argument zero.
   ```
3. In `bash`, `$@` expands as all positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`...) starting at parameter `$1`.
4. In a `bash` function, the positional parameters are the arguments passed to the function when it is called.

So, in your case, the command executed for each found file or directory is:

```
bash -c 'foo "$@"' bash <the-file>
```

The positional parameters are thus set to:

```
$0 = bash
$1 = <the-file>
```

and `bash` is asked to execute `'foo "$@"'` in this context. `"$@"` is first expanded as `"<the-file>"`. So, function `foo` is called with one single argument: `"<the-file>"`. In the context of function `foo` the positional parameters are thus:

```
$1 = "<the-file>"
```

and `echo "$@"` expands as `echo "<the-file>"`.

All this just prints the names of all found files or directories. It is almost as if you had any of:

```
find . -exec echo {} \;
find . -print
find .
find
```

(for `find` versions that accept the last one).

*Almost as if*, only, because if file or directory names contain spaces, depending on your use of `find` and of quotes, you will get different results. So, if you intend to have a more complex `foo` function, you should pay attention to the quotes. Examples:

```
$ touch "filename with spaces" plain
$ ls -1
filename with spaces
plain                                                # 2 files
$ foo() { echo "$@"; }                               # print arguments
$ find . -type f
./filename with spaces
./plain
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'foo "$@"' bash {} \;
./filename with spaces
./plain
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'foo $@' bash {} \;
./filename with spaces
./plain
```

The 3 `find` commands apparently do the same but:

```
$ bar() { echo $#; }                                 # print number of arguments
$ wc -w < <(find . -type f)
4                                                    # 4 words
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'bar "$@"' bash {} \;
1                                                    # 1 argument
1                                                    # per file
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'bar $@' bash {} \;
3                                                    # 3 arguments
1                                                    # 1 argument
```

With `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'bar "$@"' bash {} \;`, the first file name is passed to function `bar` as one single argument, while in all other cases it is considered as 3 separate arguments.

Comment: BTW, I retracted my upvote, since, IMO, the second part of the (updated) answer doesn't address OP's question and can therefore be somewhat misleading

Comment: @Leon No problem. I understand your point. I added this second part because I suspect that the real `foo` function is far more complex than what the OP shows (else, it would be about useless). And if I am not wrong, it will indeed make a difference... I tried to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thanks for the answer. But I am still confused. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Anubis Attention, in your updated question you replaced the original `$@` (which expands as all positional parameters starting at `$1`) by `$#` (number of positional parameters). I updated my answer with a slightly more detailed explanation.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet that change is not intentional. So as I get it, `bash -c 'bar "$@"' bash {}` and `bash -c 'bar "$@"' ANYTHING_HERE {}` are identical, isn't it? (Of course `ANYTHING_HERE` should be a single argument). If so why do they put `bash` there? I haven't came across this before, appreciate your help.

Comment: @Anubis *...are identical, isn't it?*: well, if you do not care about positional parameter `$0`, yes. Else, it makes a difference: the value of this parameter. *... why do they put bash there?*: because traditionally `$0` carries the name of the currently running program. In this case, the program that is called by `find` is `bash`, so it makes sense to set `$0` to `bash`.